# I can see a webpage on a local computer, but after uploading it the pictures don't appear

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use a template provided here:
http://themes.alessioatzeni.com/html/brushed/
Then, I downloaded the basic files and modified them for my purpose. It was OK. I didn't have any problem to see the pages on my computer. I tested it with Edge, Chrome, and Fire Fox. Everything showed it very well. Then, I uploaded all the files on my website:
http://hirophysics.com/japaneseusedcar/bahama-used-car.html
Then, there is no picture on the slider and also I cannot find the right and left arrows on the menu bar... 
I checked if all the file are uploaded. I found everything on the server. I didn't use any foreign language...

Would someone possibly advise me where the problem is hidden?

Thank you very much!

Hiro

Comment: please add your slider js/html/css

Comment: Check DevTools. I see a lot of 404 for `http://hirophysics.com/japaneseusedcar/_include/img/slider-images/*.jpg`

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very thankful for your insight. Right, the files are not linked. Then, I looked into the file and found that JPG (the extension) was capital... I used Windows to run the html, js, and css, but the server is on linux. It turned out to be my stupid mistake, but without you guys' pointing out, I couldn't notice it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the typical reason: wrong url to a resource. Often, when you are launching the page locally you get a bit different url than on the server. And your errors show exactly that error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

So check again, if the URL you provided is correct. And as I said, the URL might be different between local and server eventho folder looks exactly the same.

http://hirophysics.com/japaneseusedcar/_include/img/logo.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Try to use your resources with additional ".." before directory where they are (for example you have

```
       _include/img/logo.png so try ../_include/img/logo.png)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very thankful for your insight. Right, the files are not linked. Then, I looked into the file and found that JPG (the extension) was capital... I used Windows to run the html, js, and css, but the server is on linux. It turned out to be my stupid mistake, but without you guys' pointing out, I couldn't notice it. Thank you again!